# SQLite database table recreating at each application reboot

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development. I have a problem in my application. My SQLite database table 
is recreating on each system reboot, and all saved contents are wiped out from table. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

here is my Database class....

```
package Nsh.android.sms;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Helpers;

public class Database {

public static final String MYDATABASENAME="Mylanguagedbnew.db";
 public static final String MYDATABASETABLE="Mylanguagedb_table1";
public static final int MYDATABASEVERSION=1;
 public static final String KEY_id="_id";
public static final String KEY_language="languages";
public static final String KEY_description="languagedescription";
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE="create table if not exists
"+MYDATABASETABLE+" ("+KEY_id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+KEY_language+" 
text not null, "+KEY_description+ " text not null);";
private datahelper sqliteopenhelper;
public static String userselectedlang;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase;
private Context context;
 public Database(Context c){
System.out.println("DBcontext!!!1111");
 context=c; 
  }
 public Database openToread()throws android.database.SQLException{
System.out.println("DBINSERTTTTTTTTT!!!OPENREAD22222");
    sqliteopenhelper=new datahelper(context,MYDATABASENAME,null,MYDATABASEVERSION);
    System.out.println("DBINSERTTTTTTTTT!!!OPENREAD22222");
    sqlitedatabase=sqliteopenhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    System.out.println("DBINSERTTTTTTTTT!!!OPENREAD22222");
    return this;
     }
  public Database openTowrite()throws android.database.SQLException{
System.out.println("DBINSERTTTTTTTTT!!!OPENWRITE22222");
sqliteopenhelper=new datahelper(context,MYDATABASENAME,null,MYDATABASEVERSION);
sqlitedatabase=sqliteopenhelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
  }
 public void close(){
sqliteopenhelper.close();
 }  
  public Cursor retriveall(){
  System.out.println("RETRIEVE ALL OK!!!!!!!!!");
String[] columns={KEY_id,KEY_language,KEY_description};
Cursor cursor=sqlitedatabase.query(MYDATABASETABLE, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
return cursor;
  } 
  public Cursor retrivelanguages(){
String[] columns={KEY_language};
Cursor c=sqlitedatabase.query(MYDATABASETABLE, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
return c;
    }
  public Cursor retrieveselectedlanguagedecription(){
userselectedlang=listlang.selectedlanguage;
String query="select languagedescription from Mylanguagedb_table1 where languages 
      ='"+userselectedlang+"';";
Cursor c1=sqlitedatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
return c1;
   }
     public long insert(String language,String languagedescription){
System.out.println("DBINSERTTTTTTTTT!!!INSERT !!!!!!!!!1111");
ContentValues contentvalues=new ContentValues();
contentvalues.put(KEY_language,language);
contentvalues.put(KEY_description,languagedescription);
return sqlitedatabase.insert(MYDATABASETABLE, null,contentvalues);
    }
   public int deleteall(){

 return sqlitedatabase.delete(MYDATABASETABLE,null,null);
    }
   /*public int deleterow(){
String selectedrow=listlang.selectedlanguage;

return sqlitedatabase.delete(MYDATABASETABLE,selectedrow, null);
    }*/
     private static class datahelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public datahelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)
}

   }    
    }
```

Comment: Show code, in general you need to check whether the db exists before you write to it

Comment: Show your code . So we can figure out your problem.

Comment: are you using same emulator or a new one all the time

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390334/android-database-connection-error

Answer (score 0):

when app start it will create new db and table if not exist else it will continue with exit db.

put this code in **your app's Start-up Activity's onCreate()** method to check whether Database is already exist or not.

```
//this is  the name of my database
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

//this is the complete path of my database stored. you can check in DDMS
public static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.rdc.mydatabase/databases/";

Context context = getBaseContext();

boolean databaseStatus = checkDataBase( DATABASE_PATH,DATABASE_NAME);
//this will check when app start
if (databaseStatus == false) {

    DBAdapter database = new DBAdapter(context);
    //here you can call your create table method 
    //database.createLoginTable();
    Log.v("Debug", "Login table created.");
}
else{
    Log.v("Debug", "Database already exist");
}

//method to check whether db is already exist or not and returns boolean
private boolean checkDataBase(String databasePath, String databaseName) {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath + databaseName,
                    null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
            Log.v("Debug", "Database exist");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("Debug", "Database not exist");

        }
        return false;
    }
```

i hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thank you  very much for your post.....But my database is storing data i can access record .but when i shutdown my system all records get empty.and Iam inserting again why this is happening?....my database can see when emulator starts running......problem is at the time of system restart.

Comment: i am wondering to read "when i shutdown my system all records get empty".. as i can say if you are testing with emulator then --> after restart Emu, the db files you can see again when Emulator get mounted in DDMS,and once created db never get delete until we uninstall app or manually remove db  files, may i know how your dbadapter code is look like?

Comment: above i added my database code ....can u pls checkout my error...i shld be really thankful..

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using `SharedPreferences` in  `onCreate()` method  ,you can  limit the  insertion of the data (if it is fixed data) only when the app first time executed.This will solve the duplication.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME1,MODE_PRIVATE);   
        boolean first1 = pref.getBoolean(PREF_FIRST1, false);

        if(first1!=true)
        {
            getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME1,MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(PREF_FIRST1, true)
            .commit();

            // insert data here or use Background Task to do that 
        }

    }
```